# Allure-behave not reporting failed suits as 'failed'

Tags: python, bdd, allure, python-behave

I have Python bdd tests in Behave. Using version 1.2.6

The issue I'm facing is that Allure-behave reports failed suits as "Passed", even if it does show a failed step, and report it as such.

I have a behave.ini in my features folder with:

```
[behave.formatters]
allure = allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter
```

I run my tests with:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure-results
```

I do see that the result files being created by allure-behave does say the suits has passed,  and is then in turn reported as such on the Allure UI

- Did I mis something while setting-up/running tests?
- Maybe add something to the "after_scenario" method?

[image: Output from test run]

[image: Output from results in my allure-results folder]

[image: behave]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already fixed in [2.3.3b1](https://pypi.org/project/allure-behave/)
Feel free to create issues in our [repo](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python)

Comment: You've beaten me by 20 minutes!!   Updated the package and works as expected.

Thank you